# Multiple 'discard if not' in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, csv

**Context:** I want to plot some data from a CSV file with `pgfplots`. This file contains more information than needed, so I want to filter it. Filters (with `discard if not` from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178629/how-to-read-a-specific-portion-of-a-data-file-in-pgfplots) or [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58548/is-it-possible-to-change-the-color-of-a-single-bar-when-the-bar-plot-is-based-on)) work well on one column, but I get some troubles when I want to filter on several columns in the same time.

**Problem:** In my case, I want to take the intersection of 3 'discard if not' conditions. But it seems that only the last conditions is taken into account.

Here is a following **MWE**:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
    
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
    # x, y, color, shape, size
    1, 3, a, 0, 2
    2, 6, b, 0, 2
    3, 5, a, 1, 2
    4, 4, b, 1, 3
    5, 9, a, 0, 3
    6, 1, b, 1, 3
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    discard if not A/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempaa{#2}
            \ifx\tempa\tempaa
            \else
                \def\pgfmathresult{}
            \fi
        }
    },
    discard if not B/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempb{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempbb{#2}
            \ifx\tempb\tempbb
            \else
            \def\pgfmathresult{}
            \fi
        }
    },
}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[grid]          
        \addplot+[mark=+, only marks,]
            table[x expr=\thisrow{x}*1, y expr=\thisrow{y}*1, 
                    discard if not A={color}{a},
                    discard if not A={shape}{0},
                    discard if not B={size}{2},
                    ignore chars={\#}, col sep=comma,
                ] 
            {data.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the previous example, instead of plotting only 1 point, I get the 3 points corresponding to `size=2`.

Even though my question seems similar to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354144/multiple-filters-expression-for-an-axis-in-pgfplots), it is not the same since it differs from the combination of one 'discard if' and one 'discard if not' vs three 'discard if not'. But of course, I tried to use this previous question to solve my issue without any success.

**Question:** How to solve this issue, and obtain the intersection of this three `discard if not` condition with `pgfplots`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `x filter/.code` you want `x filter/.append code`. Then you only need one version.

```
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
    
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{data.csv}
    # x, y, color, shape, size
    1, 3, a, 0, 2
    2, 6, b, 0, 2
    3, 5, a, 1, 2
    4, 4, b, 1, 3
    5, 9, a, 0, 3
    6, 1, b, 1, 3
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    discard if not A/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.append code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempaa{#2}
            \ifx\tempa\tempaa
            \else
                \def\pgfmathresult{}
            \fi
        }
    }}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[grid]          
        \addplot+[mark=+, only marks,]
            table[x expr=\thisrow{x}*1, y expr=\thisrow{y}*1, 
                    discard if not A={color}{a},
                    discard if not A={shape}{0},
                    discard if not A={size}{2},
                    ignore chars={\#}, col sep=comma,
                ] 
            {data.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]